# Twitter API Always using my account

Tags: twitter

I am having the strangest problem using Twitter API. I am using a Github package dg/twitter.php.

The problem: I am making an app that sends a status update to twitter and I store the status in my database, simple. But what is happening is it stopped asking me to login and always uses my twitter account, even from different computers and clearing all cache. The strange thing is that it seems like it has cached my account and there is no way to clear it. If i completely log out of twitter and go to the app, it no longer asks me to sign in, it just uses my account, so anyone who goes to the app submits tweets as ME.

I thought it had to do with my App settings so I reset everything, renewed tokens, but still the same problem. I uploaded files to another server using the same app tokens, and yet again the same problem. My twitter app only uses MY account and will not let me login because it acts like I am already logged in when I am not.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Since this app is a Facebook app, i realized I had a problem with the oauth creating a new token because FB uses an iframe which was conflicting with the authorize abilities twitter currently has.